# Remove bin-folder from cvs project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I have some Android projects using CVS in eclipse. Long time ago when the projects were added, the bin-folder was added too. This has become more and more annoying and I would like to remove it, but how?

My attemps so far:

1. Right-clicking the bin folder and selecting Team->Add to .cvsignore is grayed out. I guess this only works when the file is new.
2. Deactivating the Project->Build Automatically, then delete the bin folder and then Commit the changes makes eclipse say: "Nothing to commit". My idea was then to activate Build Automatically again and add the new bin folder to .cvsignore.

Any ideas? If there are any suggestions circumvent eclipse I am open to that also. I have access to the server. But I'd prefer using eclipse to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "feature" of CVS. You'll need to physically remove `bin` from the CVS server file system in order to make it "forget" about that folder (be careful whenever mucking around with the filesystem of a CVS server!). You may then need to re-check-out the project in Eclipse (although I've seen it work with and without that last step).

Comment: Thanks. You lead me on the way. Here is what I did:

1. Start eclipse
2. Press F5 at the root of the project to refresh all
3. Commit all to be sure everything is in sync
4. Remove the project from eclipse
5. rm dirname -Rf on the server (in my case the bin directory)
6. Import the project from CVS back into eclipse
7. Add the bin to .cvsignore (choose Resource(s) by name)
8. Commit the changes (the .cvsignore file).

I don't think it's a very nice way and I don't hope it will some day pop up with some strange behaviour. But it seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can only ignore files that don't exist on the CVS server at all.  Could bin somehow be in the .cvsignore file as well as on the server?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with the last sentence? I've never added something to the .cvsignore, so there should not be anything concerning that locally nor on the server.